# In Node - How can I modify this code so that it pipes to a new readable stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, filestream

I have a function that should take in a filestream, parse a csv file and do some data transformation, then it should pipe the transformed data to a new readable stream for another function to accept as an input param.

Currently I have this:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const csvParse = require('csv-parse')
const transform = require('stream-transform')

let filePath
filePath = filePath || ''

export const stream = (filePath) => {
  const readerStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath)
  return readerStream
    .pipe(csvParse({relax_column_count: true}))
    .pipe(transformer)
}

const transformer = transform(function(record,cb) {
  record.forEach((cc, i, self) => {
  ...do data transformation logic here
  })
  cb(null, record.join(','))
})
```

the function that should accept a file stream looks like:

```
import {stream} from '../csvStream'
import * as formData from 'form-data'
import { createReadStream } from 'fs'
public static async uploadContent(
  file:any
) { ...some logic here

    .then(async (_err, _info) => {
    try {
      const form = new FormData()
      ...some logic here

      const isCsv = fileName.slice(fileName.length-3) === 'csv'
      if(isCsv) {
        form.append('VersionData', stream(file.path), {
          contentType: 'application/octet-stream',
        })
      } else {
        form.append('VersionData', createReadStream(file.path), {
          contentType: 'application/octet-stream',
        })
      }
      } catch(e) {
        console.log(e)
        throw(e)
      }
   })
}
```

i've only included the relevant code in the second function since it is lengthy.  The else portion succeeds while the code inside of the if statement just hangs. the issue is somewhere in my first code block, i dont think it is piping a readStream correctly.

Comment: Your "require" statement in your first code block is missing a closing quote

Comment: thanks @mrprgr that was a typo on my part when posting this question

Comment: You need to wait for the streams to finish, i don't see any `on('finish')` or `on('end')` listeners. Make the `stream` method a promise and use it with `await` in `uploadContent`